# Back button in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

Am trying to get the back button in my dialog to go back to the original screen. I don't know if I have all the imports that I need. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Java code:

```
package my.dlog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class DlogActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  Dialog dialog;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DlogActivity.this, DlogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
      }

      public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp" android:background="@drawable/mint1">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button" />

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="236dp"
      android:layout_height="220dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="100dp" android:background="@drawable/carsee"/>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry for the delay onclick was not working as i would like but its right now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onBackPressed() {
       dialog.cancel();
// Simply Dismiss the dialog to make it close and return to back..
/*What you are using is not a valid construct */   
}
```

Also make sure that **button1 in in main layout** as you have used findViewById(R.id.button1) directly for set content view

Comment: so if i take Intent intent = new Intent(DlogActivity.this, DlogActivity.class);   out then put dialog.cancel();
 in it will tell the button to go back a page from the dialog

Comment: It will close the dialog and let you go on page on which dialog is shown.. If you want to go back to a prevous page.. using finish() along with dialog.cancel

Answer (score 0):

Well normally the back button works just without any help from us.  If you take the

```
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent(DlogActivity.this, DlogActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
```

out, what happens when you press 'back'? If this is not what you want, then what do you wnat to happen? If there are no errors, I would think you have the required imports.
Cliff

Comment: i just want a button on dialog page to  close when the ueser presses the button i cant get it to go back once iv pressd it